# Error when downloading software update

Tags: updates, system-error, samsung-knox, samsung-galaxy-s8+

I have a galaxy s8+ (model number: SM-G955F). It is knox tripped but the build status is still official. But when trying to update to the April 1st 2021 software update it downloads all the way, does a restart but then says error and does not update. Is there a way to fix it or does the fact that knox is tripped mean I can no longer update security patches?

Comment: You could try to install the latest original firmware version using a PC running Odin/Heimdall. As the original firmware version is properly signed it should not change the state of your phone.

Answer (score 0):

I Updated it by downloading the Samsung Smart Switch app. The app detected that it was on an older version and automatically downloaded the update